# CloudFront CDN for S3 bucket which is cross region replicated

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication, amazon-cloudfront

Given yesterday's us-east-1 S3 outage, how do I best architect a CloudFront CDN which uses a S3 bucket as the source and the bucket is setup to replicate to another region?

1. Do I setup two separate CloudFront CDNs, one with the bucket in us-east-1 as the origin and another CloudFront CDN with the replicated bucket in us-east-2 as the origin and then use one Route53 record to access the two CDNs?

or

2. Can I setup one CloudFront CDN with two Origins (one in us-east-1 and the other in us-east-2) and CloudFront will automatically pull the content from the S3 region which is working?

Any other solution?

Your insights and comments are much appreciated.

Cheers
Bernie

Comment: Neither of these solutions will work as expected.  I will attempt to explain why (and propose an alternative) in an answer as time permits.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Looking forward to your explanation.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Would a better approach be to create a CNAME in Route 53 with Failover and Healthcheck pointing directly to the S3 URLs and then create a Cloudfront CDN using the CNAME?

Comment: sorry I haven't gotten back with the promised answer yet.  I'm not quite sure what you're planning to do with the CNAME you're talking about, here, but the fundamental problem is that you can't have two buckets responding to the same hostname.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I put my idea in a quick diagram at https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1K_u9zqJGyYBYGTAl0x0uw6waA-_2rZrS96pUP0PBNBI/edit?usp=sharing Please let me know what you think or if the link doesn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work.  To access a bucket with a custom hostname, that hostname has to be the name of the bucket itself.  Only one bucket in one region can have any given name -- the bucket namespace is global.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Wow, I wasn't aware of that s3 cname restriction. That stinks. I'm starting to get the feeling that regional failover can't be achieved using cloudfront and s3...

Comment: It can, but as far as I have been able to determine, it is not currently possible without help from some additional components, such as proxies running in EC2.  This creates a potential new point of failure, but it's in the failover path, and it's one that you control -- which was not the case with the outage last week.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot You mean something like this? https://docs.google.com/drawings/d/1alyYA6yCzgL1tFICxGH-c9JHInRtK6NjPoPUjsvnrxc/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Yes, that's the general idea.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that neither of my proposals worked and that Cloudfront does not support S3 replication and failover out of the box.

Below architecture should have survived the 2/28/17 North Virginia S3 outage (Thanks for the help @Michael-sqlbot).

I am surprised though that AWS does not offer a more trivial solution for such a fairly common scenario...
[image: S3 Failover With Cloudfront]

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use S3 cross-region replication. To do, please follow the instructions in the aws blog: [s3 cross-region replication- how to](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cross-region-replication-for-amazon-s3/)
2. Unfortunately, multi-region replication is not supported by CloudFront at the moment. But, as CloudFront uses multiple caches or edge locations, you are assured your data is safe.

I would personally select your first choice as S3 has 99.99.. durability and is highly available. So, that's an ideal solution to assure your replicated data remains highly available. Further, if your data volume is high, you can store your old replicated data with Amazon Glacier. However, this is a tradeoff between how critical your data is and how much time you consider for this valuable data to be recovered; because Amazon Glacier may take up to few hours to bring your archived data back up for usage.

Comment: I tried and it looked promising until I ran into a little hurdle.

Comment: I created two separate Cloudfront distributions; one for the replicated bucket in each region.  The issue is that in cloudfront when I setup the cname of the 2nd cdn, I get an error saying that the cname already exits. It indeed does already exist, as I used the same cname in the first cdn distribution.  Not sure how to get around this...

Answer (score 1):

You can create cross-region replication and use your CloudFront with multiple origins.

Also you will need to write explicit rules, how your content will be routed with multiple origins.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/distribution-web-values-specify.html#DownloadDistValuesPathPattern

Comment: Will this really work? The same identical files exist in both s3 regions. How would I write a rule that says first try this file in origin 1 and if I get an error back then try origin 2.